# Proof environment with long header causes many problems. How to avoid them?

Tags: amsmath, amsthm, proof-package

Suppose we have defined a `lemma` environment with the `amstheorem` package. And suppose the `proof` environment is available via the `ams` packages. Please consider this example.

```
\begin{lemma}
\label{lem:euler}
Euler is the greatest mathematician of all times.
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}[Proof of Lemma~\ref{lem:euler} under the additional assumption that there
exists a unique mathematician of all times and that this unique mathematician of all times
has a magnitude]
Indeed, under the above assumption, the magnitude is given by the greatness. But if there
is only one mathematician, he is automatically the greatest. Since Euler was a mathematician,
we are done.
\end{proof}
```

When coding such long proof headers, I have many problems.

- It may happen that the proof header is longer than a line. It will not fit in a line but it does not break automatically.
- I cannot use display math in the proof header.
- I have no problem with the obligatory period at the end. For several sentences, I can omit the last period manually. No deal!
- Even if the header fits in a line but is close to the end, and I start writing my paragraph inside the proof, that new paragraph will not spread out nicely, but rather goes over the margin (with an `overfull boxes` madness). It does not help to insert `newline` manually. The text simply does not spread out, but is left aligned.
- Suppose I want to start a new line after the long header, the best I know to do is `\mbox{}\newline` because a simple `newline` is not recognized as a line directly after `[text]` (`->warning`).

How can I avoid these problems? How do I typeset this correctly? I thank everyone for suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid long labels. Anyway, here's how you can do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[]
  {\itshape #1\@addpunct{.}}\hskip\labelsep\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}\label{lem:euler}
Euler is the greatest mathematician of all times.
\end{lemma}


\begin{proof}[Proof of Lemma~\ref{lem:euler} under the additional assumption that there
exists a unique mathematician of all times and that this unique mathematician of all times
has a magnitude]
Indeed, under the above assumption, the magnitude is given by the greatness. But if there
is only one mathematician, he is automatically the greatest. Since Euler was a mathematician,
we are done.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will try out your solution tomorrow!